# Calling Java from MATLAB?

Tags: java, matlab

I want Matlab program to call a java file, preferably with an example.

Comment: please read the documentation. [Using Java Libraries from MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to give a mini-example here.  Either use the java functions right from the Matlab window as zellus suggests, or, if need permits, create your own java class.  Here's an example:

```
package testMatlabInterface;

public class TestFunction
{
  private double value;

  public TestFunction()
  {
      value = 0;
  }

  public double Add(double v)
  {
      value += v;
      return value;
  }
}
```

Then turn it into a jar file.  Assuming you put the file in a folder called `testMatlabInterface`, run this command at the command line:

```
jar cvf testMatlab.jar testMatlabInterface
```

Then, in Matlab, navigate to the directory where your `testMatlab.jar` file is located and run the command, `import testMatlabInterface.*` to import all the classes in the `testMatlabInterface` package.  Then you may use the class like so:

```
>> methodsview testMatlabInterface.TestFunction
>> me = testMatlabInterface.TestFunction()

me =

testMatlabInterface.TestFunction@7e413c

>> me.Add(10)

ans =

    10

>> me.Add(10)

ans =

    20

>> me.Add(10)

ans =

    30
```

Let me know if I can be of further assistance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your post has been very helpful.

Answer (score 29):

There are three cases to consider.

1. Java built-in libraries.

   That is, anything described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). These items can simply be called directly.  For example:

   ```
   map = java.util.HashMap;
   map.put(1,10);
   map.put(2,30);
   map.get(1)   %returns 10
   ```

   The only complication is the mapping Matlab performs between Matlab data types and Java data types.  These mappings are described [here (Matlab to Java)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-java-methods.html) and [here (Java to Matlab)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-data-returned-from-java-methods.html).  (tl; dr:  usually the mappings are as you would expect)
2. Precompiled *.jar files

   You first need to add these to Matlab's java class path.  You can do this dynamically (that is, per-Matlab session, with no required Matlab state), as follows:

   ```
   javaaddpath('c:\full\path\to\compiledjarfile.jar')
   ```

   You can also add these statically by editing the classpath.txt file.  For more information use `docsearch java class path`.
3. Precompiled *.class files.

   These are similar to *.jar file, except you need to add the directory containing the class file, rather than the class files themselves.  For example:

   ```
   javaaddpath('c:\full\path\to\directory\containing\class\files\')  
   %NOT THIS:  javaaddpath('c:\full\path\to\directory\containing\class\files\classname.class')
   ```

Comment: class not found exception, although I have added the path

Comment: @zinking make sure when you compile your Java classes, you're targeting a JRE version at least as old as the one that ships with the MATLAB release you're using.  If your classfiles have a newer version number than that supported by MATLAB's JRE, they won't be loaded and you'll get a ClassNotFoundException when you try to use them.  For example, R2006b ships with JRE5, so you need to use `javac --source 1.5 --target 1.5 <other arguments>` if you're compiling with JDK6 or newer.