# JAVA download command in matlab code

Tags: java, matlab, download

I am trying to find a way to get rid of the matlab download command urlwrite because I can not see the download progress.
I am downloading a 500MB file with

```
 urlwrite('http://example.com/testfile','C:/work');
```

Because I can not see the estimate time or the download progress I wanna replace that command with a JAVA code.
Does anybody know how to do that in MATLAB?
Thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520503/calling-java-from-matlab

Comment: The underlying `urlreadwrite` is based on Java already so you can look at how it works: `edit private/urlreadwrite`. By the way, Octave's version of [`urlwrite`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/URL-Manipulation.html#doc%2durlwrite) apparently supports some form of progress indication so maybe it's code would be useful.

Comment: You could check the size of the temp file to know the progress.