# Call a java function from matlab script

Tags: java, matlab, training-data, nntool

I'm trying to call a java function from a `Matlab` script, I tried all the solutions put in the website but I didn't get an issue.
My class is simple:

```
  package testMatlabInterface;

public class TestFunction
{
  private double value;

  public TestFunction()
  {
      value=0;
  }

  public double Add(double v)
  {
      value += v;
      return value;
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {

  }
}
```

So I put `.java` file (also `.class`) in my workingspace `C:\scriptsMatlab` and I added this path to `javaclasspath` of Matlab, but when I try to call the function , it tells me that there's no class with this name in `javaclasspath` of `Matlab`.

**EDIT:**
Here's the version of java that Matlab uses:

```
Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode
```

And this is the version on jdk which I used to compile my class :
[image]

But when I try to execute this commande from matlab

```
>> javaaddpath 'C:\scriptsMatlab'
>> obj = TestFunction
```

it tells me:

```
Undefined function or variable 'TestFunction'.
```

Comment: Probably need single quotes for the argument. What happens if you try `import MyFunction.*`?

Comment: it imports it but it can't recognize the class

Comment: I tried to follow the answer of macduff here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520503/calling-java-from-matlab

but i get stuck in ' methodsview testMatlabInterface.TestFunction' it says that 'No class testMatlabInterface.TestFunction can be located or no
methods for class'

Comment: which java version did you use to compile your class? It's best to use the same major version as your Matlab uses, otherwise it may not work.

Comment: It's the same version, you can see my question after editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

1. Check if same JRE/JDK is being used to compile your JAVA file. Execute on Matlab:

   ```
   version -java
   ```
2. Compie your ***MyFunction.java*** with **same jdk** as above , and locate your ***MyFunction.class***
3. Locate your Matlab classpath.txt. Type following into matlab cmd.

   ```
   which classpath.txt
   ```
4. Open your classpath.txt as administrator.Add the full path for the directory with the ***MyFunction.class***  to the end of the 'classpath.txt' file as a single line and save the file.
5. Restart Matlab.
6. To run in Matlab . Create object of MyFunction.

   ```
   obj = MyFunction
   ```

   To run main() method in matlab.

   ```
   javaMethod('main', obj, '')
   ```

---

**Option 2**

Follow Steps 1-2.

Execute following command in Matlab

`JAVAADDPATH PATH/to/Directoryof MyFunction.class`.

No need to restart Matlab here.
Just run using

```
obj = MyFunction;
javaMethod('main', obj);
```

From MathWorks :

> javaMethod(MethodName,JavaObj,x1,...,xN) calls the method in the class of the Java® object array with the signature matching the arguments x1,...,xN.
>
> javaMethod(StaticMethodName,ClassName,x1,...,xN) calls the static method in class ClassName.

Comment: Should you not call obj = MyFunction . What is TestFunction ?

Comment: Sorry I just changed the test function with another

Comment: did you follow option 1 ? add testfunction.class with package directory to your matlab cp ?

Comment: Classpath is not being added properly . Check javaclasspath. also try following
javaaddpath('directory where the .class file resides');
a = TestFunction(); //Creates an object of the java class.
methodsview(a); // displays all the methods.
a.Add() ; calls the Java method Add().
After you add classpath check classpath.txt of matlab , does it have the cp of .class file. Also remove the .java in the directory. only keep the .class in the classpath

Comment: It's bizarre that there isn't something more convenient than this.