# HelloWorld.java from matlab

Tags: java, matlab

Trying to call this function from matlab

```
package a.b;

public class TestFunction { 
public TestFunction(){
}
public static void HelloWorld() {
 System.out.println("Hello, World");
 }
}
```

I compiled it and got a class file:

```
[idf@localhost b]$ ls
TestFunction.class  TestFunction.java
[idf@localhost b]$ pwd
/home/idf/Documents/java/a/b
[idf@localhost b]$
```

I added the path to the parent directory in matlab

```
javaaddpath('/home/idf/Documents/java/')
```

If I try to import the package or call it I get errors:

```
>> import a.b
Error using import
Import argument 'a.b' cannot be found or cannot be imported.
```

How do I call the `java` function `TestFunction.HelloWorld` from `matlab`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a java function from matlab script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989040/call-a-java-function-from-matlab-script)

Comment: That's helpful. It looks like the java that I am using, Java build 1.8.0_151-b12,  is not the same as the one in matlab: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> import a.b
Error using import
Import argument 'a.b' cannot be found or cannot be imported.
```

This tells Matlab to import a class called `b` from a package called `a`.  To import all classes in the package `a.b`, do this:

```
>> import a.b.*
```

To import just `TestFunction`

```
>> import a.b.TestFunction
```

Reference: [matlab documentation for `import`](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#buvf5jb-3)

Comment: Thanks, along with the above comment by vinS, I was able to resolve issue. I had to 1) change the MATLAB_JAVA export to point to the new Oracle java, javaaddpath to the actual directory where compiled class resides, then use your post.